# Kubernetes Job is not getting terminated even after specifying "activeDeadlineSeconds"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

My yaml file

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: auto
  labels:
    app: auto
spec:
  backoffLimit: 5
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auto
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: auto
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
      imagePullSecrets: 
      - name: imageregistery
      restartPolicy: Never
```

The pods are killed appropriately but the job ceases to kill itself post 100 seconds.

Is there anything that we could do to kill the job post the container/pod's functionality is completed.

```
kubectl version --short

Client Version: v1.6.1
Server Version: v1.13.10+IKS


kubectl get jobs --namespace abc
NAME          DESIRED   SUCCESSFUL   AGE
auto   1         1            26m
```

Thank you,

Comment: Kubernetes is keeping pods around so you can get the logs,configuration etc from it, I think you can use TTLAfterFinished to get remove the pod faster

Comment: @ErezBenHarush, Can u please give me an example of TTLAAfterFinished on my xml file...........That i could use???

Comment: That also did not cleanup the job. My Code: spec: backoffLimit: 5 #activeDeadlineSeconds: 100 ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100

Answer (score 1):

The default way to delete jobs after they are done is to use `kubectl delete` command.

As mentioned by @Erez:

> Kubernetes is keeping pods around so you can get the
>   logs,configuration etc from it.

If you don't want to do that manually you could write a script running in your cluster that would check for jobs with completed status and than delete them.

Another way would be to use TTL feature that deletes the jobs automatically after a specified number of seconds. However, **if you set it to zero it will clean them up immediately**. For more details of how to set it up look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup).

Please let me know if that helped.